# Angular 7 / Express Session not persisting

Tags: angular, express, angular7

I have an Angular 7 app connecting to a Express API backend and the session doesn't seem to persist.

In Express I have the following endpoint:

```
router.get('/getsession', function(req, res) {
    console.log(`Session ID: ${req.session.id}`);
    res.status(200).json({ sessionid: req.session.id });
});
```

Here's an example of the output for two consecutive runs of `/getsession`:

> Session ID: NMi8AXhX1wf9xui0WDFwENZ_3QON_iYN
>
> Session ID: pNWcPTeJVlC8rKySw6ty5xSPa9sSME8x

I've enabled the Credentials header for Express, so it will accept it:

```
const cors = require("cors"); 
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
}));
```

And I've also enabled `withCredentials` for `Angular HttpClient`, so that it will send the cookie along with the POST request:

```
API_URL: string = "http://localdev.com:4200/api";
options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Credentials': 'same-origin'
  }),
  withCredentials: true,
}

getSessionInfo() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/users/getsession`, { withCredentials: true })
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

There's an Angular proxy from `localhost:4200` to `localhost:4044` so the API requests can be processed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Interestingly enough, the cookie is being passed properly onto Express, however it's still creating a new session for each request. The following is the result of `req.session` when calling the `/getsession` endpoint.

> { 'if-none-match': 'W/"b8-afvqPuftgTLN3Wn5o/ZQx8jUsv0"',
>
> cookie: '_ga=GA1.2.1851469997.1544357368; _gid=GA1.2.1246771476.1544357368; _gat_gtag_UA_99682244_1=1',
>
> 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bg;q=0.8,mt;q=0.7',
>
> 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>
> referer: 'http://localdev.com:4200/user/register',
>
> 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
>
> accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
>
> connection: 'close',
>
> host: 'localdev.com:4044' }
>
> Session ID: XWKGlJPrzYeRBU3Hi7RIAaWpowGU6Fuz
>
> { 'if-none-match': 'W/"b8-mMGAHD1Tmbv1r5T+YChLkQoq988"',
>
> cookie: '_ga=GA1.2.1851469997.1544357368; _gid=GA1.2.1246771476.1544357368; _gat_gtag_UA_99682244_1=1',
>
> 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bg;q=0.8,mt;q=0.7',
>
> 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>
> referer: 'http://localdev.com:4200/user/register',
>
> 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
>
> accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
>
> connection: 'close',
>
> host: 'localdev.com:4044' }
>
> Session ID: T4SnSqGfo9lOWGpiyPQS0LLJgXsRnZ4T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. When running in a dev environment without and SSL certificate, the cookie gets sent properly with the above configuration, however you also need to set the cookie secure to `false` so that it will be used.

Did it the following way:

```
let sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: { secure: false },
    store: new MemcachedStore({
        hosts: ['127.0.0.1:11211'],
    })
});
```